# Iterating through pairs (or more) of objects in C++

Tags: c++, python, iterator

I know you can iterate through a container like this:

```
for(double x : mycontainer)
```

Which is analogous to Python's

```
for x in mylist:
```

However, sometimes I need access to an element in another container with the same index and I have to make an ordinary for loop. In Python, alternatively, I can do (for two or more lists):

```
for (x,y) in zip(xlist, ylist):
```

Is there something similar in C++?

Comment: Boost [Zip Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Nice one. But I thought there would be something in C++11 standard?

Comment: I don't think the standard includes a zip iterator (yet, anyway), though some of the sample code for variadic templates (in section §14.5.3/5) looks suspiciously similar.

Comment: What is the body of your for loop? Maybe there is something in <algorithm> (like `transform`...)

Comment: @hansmaad Well, I was thinking about some general solution for this sort of problems rather than some particular situation.

Comment: The "general solution" is to avoid "raw loops" as much as possible and use standard algorithms.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it? I don't like having questions hanging like this with no conclusion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest analog of which I'm aware is Boost's [zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

In a typical case, you'd use `boost::make_zip_iterator` along with `boost:make_tuple`, so you'd end up with something like:

```
boost::make_zip_iterator(boost:make_tuple(xlist.begin(), ylist.begin()))
```

and:

```
boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(xlist.end(), ylist.end()))
```

This is, unfortunately, quite a bit more verbose than the Python version, but such is life sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Closest thing which I know is `boost::combine` (though, I don't see documentation for it - and actually, there is [trac ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8028) for adding it). It uses [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) internally, but it is more convenient:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3efed9474c756d)

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace std;

    int x[3] = {1,2,3};
    double y[3] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};

    for(const auto &p : combine(x,y))
        cout << get<0>(p) << " " << get<1>(p) << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
1 1.1
2 2.2
3 3.3
```